# ¿Es posible añadir persistencia y sincronización a un documento en específico en Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Anteriormente estaba usando Realtime Database de [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase), y podía añadir persistencia y sincronización a un nodo en específico de la base de datos haciendo esto:

```
DatabaseReference santosRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("santos");
santosRef.keepSynced(true);
```

Con esto me sincroniza el nodo `santos` de RTDB, la cual se presenta así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He pasado esta parte de mi base de datos a `Firestore`, pero en la documentación no encontré explicada la forma de sincronizar solamente el documento que guarda la información sobre `santos`.

La base de datos está organizada así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y [en la documentación explican](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline?hl=es-419) que la persistencia se establece así:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
            .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

Pero nunca hablan sobre establecer persistencia/sincronización de un documento en específico.

**¿Es posible en `Firestore` establecer persistencia solamente a documentos específicos?  ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?**

Answer (score 0):

En realtime database, **`keepSynced`** hace que la ruta indicada se actualice automáticamente sin necesidad de un "**`listener`**". Para Firestore parece que no hay algo equivalente aún, sólo los "**`listeners`**", que puedes crear de este sencillo modo:

Por ejemplo, para estar al tanto de los cambios en un documento:

```
db.collection("micoleccion")
  .doc("DocId")
  .onSnapshot(
      function (snapshot) {},
      function (error) {}
  );
```

Practicamente igual para estar al tanto de los cambios de un grupo de documentos:

```
db.collection("micoleccion")
  .where("campo", "==", "valor")
  .onSnapshot(
      function (snapshot) {},
      function (error) {}
  );
```

O en una colección:

```
db.collection("micoleccion")
  .onSnapshot(
      function (snapshot) {},
      function (error) {}
  );
```

Hay más cosas que pueden hacerse, checa la documentación:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero lo que hace el código de RTDB indicado es dar persistencia a los datos, o sea, los deja disponibles en el dispositivo aún sin que tenga conexión a internet. Eso es lo que quisiera hacer con Firestore pero sólo para una parte de los datos.

Comment: El cache está disponible automáticamente en Firestore, le llaman "offline persistence". Para móviles está activado por defecto: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data

Comment: ¿Entonces no hay forma en `Firestore` de sincronizar/persistir únicamente un determinado nodo completo? La cuestión es que tengo una app con muchísimo contenido, varias tablas con miles de páginas de texto y no me interesa sincronizar todo fuera de línea, sino sólo una parte de ese contenido el cual se requiere completo para gente que a lo mejor tiene acceso a internet una vez al mes y quiere tener todo el contenido de ese nodo en local. Esa gente no usa todo el contenido de la base de datos, solamente parte de él en un módulo en específico.